# Winscp with SSIS package gives System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.UnsafeInvokeInternal(Object obj, Object[] parameters,) ERROR

Tags: c#, ssis

Hello I have a c# script to upload files from SQL to SFTP folder. However I am facim this error:
[image]

I do not know waht to do, maybe some configurations is wrong. I have been checking on the internet some solutions one of them is related to GAC I tried this, but not works.

C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v10.0A\bin\NETFX 4.6.1 Tools\gacutil.exe /i WinSCPnet.dl

[image]

I am getting desesperated once I need to finish my project and I do not kno how solve this.

Anyone can help me?
Thanks

cod c#

```
``´`#region Help:  Introduction to the script task
/* The Script Task allows you to perform virtually any operation that can be accomplished in
 * a .Net application within the context of an Integration Services control flow. 
 * 
 * Expand the other regions which have "Help" prefixes for examples of specific ways to use
 * Integration Services features within this script task. */
#endregion


#region Namespaces
using System;
using System.Data;
using Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.IO;
using System.Reflection;
using WinSCP;
#endregion

namespace ST_3ab2d9489ca34ca196ad355b5dd03f43
{
    /// <summary>
    /// ScriptMain is the entry point class of the script.  Do not change the name, attributes,
    /// or parent of this class.
    /// </summary>
    [Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Tasks.ScriptTask.SSISScriptTaskEntryPointAttribute]
    public partial class ScriptMain : Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Tasks.ScriptTask.VSTARTScriptObjectModelBase
    {
        #region Help:  Using Integration Services variables and parameters in a script
        /* To use a variable in this script, first ensure that the variable has been added to 
         * either the list contained in the ReadOnlyVariables property or the list contained in 
         * the ReadWriteVariables property of this script task, according to whether or not your
         * code needs to write to the variable.  To add the variable, save this script, close this instance of
         * Visual Studio, and update the ReadOnlyVariables and 
         * ReadWriteVariables properties in the Script Transformation Editor window.
         * To use a parameter in this script, follow the same steps. Parameters are always read-only.
         * 
         * Example of reading from a variable:
         *  DateTime startTime = (DateTime) Dts.Variables["System::StartTime"].Value;
         * 
         * Example of writing to a variable:
         *  Dts.Variables["User::myStringVariable"].Value = "new value";
         * 
         * Example of reading from a package parameter:
         *  int batchId = (int) Dts.Variables["$Package::batchId"].Value;
         *  
         * Example of reading from a project parameter:
         *  int batchId = (int) Dts.Variables["$Project::batchId"].Value;
         * 
         * Example of reading from a sensitive project parameter:
         *  int batchId = (int) Dts.Variables["$Project::batchId"].GetSensitiveValue();
         * */

        #endregion

        #region Help:  Firing Integration Services events from a script
        /* This script task can fire events for logging purposes.
         * 
         * Example of firing an error event:
         *  Dts.Events.FireError(18, "Process Values", "Bad value", "", 0);
         * 
         * Example of firing an information event:
         *  Dts.Events.FireInformation(3, "Process Values", "Processing has started", "", 0, ref fireAgain)
         * 
         * Example of firing a warning event:
         *  Dts.Events.FireWarning(14, "Process Values", "No values received for input", "", 0);
         * */
        #endregion

        #region Help:  Using Integration Services connection managers in a script
        /* Some types of connection managers can be used in this script task.  See the topic 
         * "Working with Connection Managers Programatically" for details.
         * 
         * Example of using an ADO.Net connection manager:
         *  object rawConnection = Dts.Connections["Sales DB"].AcquireConnection(Dts.Transaction);
         *  SqlConnection myADONETConnection = (SqlConnection)rawConnection;
         *  //Use the connection in some code here, then release the connection
         *  Dts.Connections["Sales DB"].ReleaseConnection(rawConnection);
         *
         * Example of using a File connection manager
         *  object rawConnection = Dts.Connections["Prices.zip"].AcquireConnection(Dts.Transaction);
         *  string filePath = (string)rawConnection;
         *  //Use the connection in some code here, then release the connection
         *  Dts.Connections["Prices.zip"].ReleaseConnection(rawConnection);
         * */
        #endregion


        /// <summary>
        /// This method is called when this script task executes in the control flow.
        /// Before returning from this method, set the value of Dts.TaskResult to indicate success or failure.
        /// To open Help, press F1.
        /// </summary>
        public void Main()
        {
            String HostName = (String)Dts.Variables["User::HostName"].Value;
            int PortNumber = (int)Dts.Variables["User::PortNumber"].Value;
            String Username = (String)Dts.Variables["User::Username"].Value;
            String Password = (String)Dts.Variables["User::Password"].Value;
            String FileLocation = (String)Dts.Variables["User::FileLocation"].Value;
            String FileName = (String)Dts.Variables["User::FileName"].Value;
            String RemoteLocation = (String)Dts.Variables["User::RemoteLocation"].Value;
            String SshPrivateKeyPath = (String)Dts.Variables["User::SshPrivateKeyPath"].Value;
            
            try
            {
                // Setup session options
                SessionOptions sessionOptions = new SessionOptions
                {
                    Protocol = Protocol.Sftp,
                    HostName = HostName,
                    UserName = Username,
                    PrivateKeyPassphrase = Password,
                    PortNumber = PortNumber,
                };

                if(SshPrivateKeyPath != "")
                {
                    sessionOptions.GiveUpSecurityAndAcceptAnySshHostKey = true;
                    sessionOptions.SshPrivateKeyPath = SshPrivateKeyPath;
                }

                using (Session session = new Session())
                {
                    session.ExecutablePath = "C:\\Shares\\Pay$\\Scripts\\WinSCP.exe";

                    // Connect
                    session.Open(sessionOptions);

                    // Upload files
                    TransferOptions transferOptions = new TransferOptions();
                    transferOptions.TransferMode = TransferMode.Binary;

                    TransferOperationResult transferResult;
                    transferResult = session.PutFiles(FileLocation + FileName, RemoteLocation, false, transferOptions);

                    // Throw on any error
                    transferResult.Check();

                    // Print results
                    bool fireAgain = false;
                    foreach (TransferEventArgs transfer in transferResult.Transfers)
                    {
                        Dts.Events.FireInformation(3, "sFTP", "Upload Succeed", transfer.FileName, 0, ref fireAgain);
                    }
                    Dts.TaskResult = (int)ScriptResults.Success;
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Dts.Events.FireError(18, "sFTP Upload Error: {" + HostName + "}", e.ToString(), "", 0);
                Dts.TaskResult = (int)ScriptResults.Failure;
            }
        }
       

        #region ScriptResults declaration
        /// <summary>
        /// This enum provides a convenient shorthand within the scope of this class for setting the
        /// result of the script.
        /// 
        /// This code was generated automatically.
        /// </summary>
        enum ScriptResults
        {
            Success = Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.DTSExecResult.Success,
            Failure = Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.DTSExecResult.Failure
        };
        #endregion

    }
}
```

Comment: When a script task goes wrong it throws that generic error message.  To get more detail, wrap it in a try..catch and raise an ssis error event in the catch block to return the error message.  You can also provide your script task code and we can see if anything seems amiss.

Comment: I have added the script in C# that I am using in SSIS package.

Comment: Did you already have that try..catch block in there?  If so, I would wrap the variable section in the try block as well and run it again to see if that is where the error is coming from.

Comment: Do you have this code?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand - do you mean the `try` change that I am suggesting?  If so, I only mean that in the Main() method to move the start of the `try{` line to above `String Hostname`.  If this is not what you are asking for, please clarify

Comment: I am not inderstand what do you mean.

Comment: I'll show you in an answer - try that out and see if you get a more meaningful error message.

Answer (score -1):

Please try this version, expanding the `Try` block, and see if you get a more meaningful error message:

```
#region Help:  Introduction to the script task
/* The Script Task allows you to perform virtually any operation that can be accomplished in
 * a .Net application within the context of an Integration Services control flow. 
 * 
 * Expand the other regions which have "Help" prefixes for examples of specific ways to use
 * Integration Services features within this script task. */
#endregion


#region Namespaces
using System;
using System.Data;
using Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.IO;
using System.Reflection;
using WinSCP;
#endregion

namespace ST_3ab2d9489ca34ca196ad355b5dd03f43
{
    /// <summary>
    /// ScriptMain is the entry point class of the script.  Do not change the name, attributes,
    /// or parent of this class.
    /// </summary>
    [Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Tasks.ScriptTask.SSISScriptTaskEntryPointAttribute]
    public partial class ScriptMain : Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Tasks.ScriptTask.VSTARTScriptObjectModelBase
    {
        #region Help:  Using Integration Services variables and parameters in a script
        /* To use a variable in this script, first ensure that the variable has been added to 
         * either the list contained in the ReadOnlyVariables property or the list contained in 
         * the ReadWriteVariables property of this script task, according to whether or not your
         * code needs to write to the variable.  To add the variable, save this script, close this instance of
         * Visual Studio, and update the ReadOnlyVariables and 
         * ReadWriteVariables properties in the Script Transformation Editor window.
         * To use a parameter in this script, follow the same steps. Parameters are always read-only.
         * 
         * Example of reading from a variable:
         *  DateTime startTime = (DateTime) Dts.Variables["System::StartTime"].Value;
         * 
         * Example of writing to a variable:
         *  Dts.Variables["User::myStringVariable"].Value = "new value";
         * 
         * Example of reading from a package parameter:
         *  int batchId = (int) Dts.Variables["$Package::batchId"].Value;
         *  
         * Example of reading from a project parameter:
         *  int batchId = (int) Dts.Variables["$Project::batchId"].Value;
         * 
         * Example of reading from a sensitive project parameter:
         *  int batchId = (int) Dts.Variables["$Project::batchId"].GetSensitiveValue();
         * */

        #endregion

        #region Help:  Firing Integration Services events from a script
        /* This script task can fire events for logging purposes.
         * 
         * Example of firing an error event:
         *  Dts.Events.FireError(18, "Process Values", "Bad value", "", 0);
         * 
         * Example of firing an information event:
         *  Dts.Events.FireInformation(3, "Process Values", "Processing has started", "", 0, ref fireAgain)
         * 
         * Example of firing a warning event:
         *  Dts.Events.FireWarning(14, "Process Values", "No values received for input", "", 0);
         * */
        #endregion

        #region Help:  Using Integration Services connection managers in a script
        /* Some types of connection managers can be used in this script task.  See the topic 
         * "Working with Connection Managers Programatically" for details.
         * 
         * Example of using an ADO.Net connection manager:
         *  object rawConnection = Dts.Connections["Sales DB"].AcquireConnection(Dts.Transaction);
         *  SqlConnection myADONETConnection = (SqlConnection)rawConnection;
         *  //Use the connection in some code here, then release the connection
         *  Dts.Connections["Sales DB"].ReleaseConnection(rawConnection);
         *
         * Example of using a File connection manager
         *  object rawConnection = Dts.Connections["Prices.zip"].AcquireConnection(Dts.Transaction);
         *  string filePath = (string)rawConnection;
         *  //Use the connection in some code here, then release the connection
         *  Dts.Connections["Prices.zip"].ReleaseConnection(rawConnection);
         * */
        #endregion


        /// <summary>
        /// This method is called when this script task executes in the control flow.
        /// Before returning from this method, set the value of Dts.TaskResult to indicate success or failure.
        /// To open Help, press F1.
        /// </summary>
        public void Main()
        {
        String HostName;
        int PortNumber;
        String Username;
        String Password;
        String FileLocation;
        String FileName;
        String RemoteLocation;
            try
            {
            HostName = (String)Dts.Variables["User::HostName"].Value;
            PortNumber = (int)Dts.Variables["User::PortNumber"].Value;
            Username = (String)Dts.Variables["User::Username"].Value;
            Password = (String)Dts.Variables["User::Password"].Value;
            FileLocation = (String)Dts.Variables["User::FileLocation"].Value;
            FileName = (String)Dts.Variables["User::FileName"].Value;
            RemoteLocation = (String)Dts.Variables["User::RemoteLocation"].Value;
            SshPrivateKeyPath = (String)Dts.Variables["User::SshPrivateKeyPath"].Value;
            

                // Setup session options
                SessionOptions sessionOptions = new SessionOptions
                {
                    Protocol = Protocol.Sftp,
                    HostName = HostName,
                    UserName = Username,
                    PrivateKeyPassphrase = Password,
                    PortNumber = PortNumber,
                };

                if(SshPrivateKeyPath != "")
                {
                    sessionOptions.GiveUpSecurityAndAcceptAnySshHostKey = true;
                    sessionOptions.SshPrivateKeyPath = SshPrivateKeyPath;
                }

                using (Session session = new Session())
                {
                    session.ExecutablePath = "C:\\Shares\\Pay$\\Scripts\\WinSCP.exe";

                    // Connect
                    session.Open(sessionOptions);

                    // Upload files
                    TransferOptions transferOptions = new TransferOptions();
                    transferOptions.TransferMode = TransferMode.Binary;

                    TransferOperationResult transferResult;
                    transferResult = session.PutFiles(FileLocation + FileName, RemoteLocation, false, transferOptions);

                    // Throw on any error
                    transferResult.Check();

                    // Print results
                    bool fireAgain = false;
                    foreach (TransferEventArgs transfer in transferResult.Transfers)
                    {
                        Dts.Events.FireInformation(3, "sFTP", "Upload Succeed", transfer.FileName, 0, ref fireAgain);
                    }
                    Dts.TaskResult = (int)ScriptResults.Success;
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Dts.Events.FireError(18, "sFTP Upload Error: {" + HostName + "}", e.ToString(), "", 0);
                Dts.TaskResult = (int)ScriptResults.Failure;
            }
        }
       

        #region ScriptResults declaration
        /// <summary>
        /// This enum provides a convenient shorthand within the scope of this class for setting the
        /// result of the script.
        /// 
        /// This code was generated automatically.
        /// </summary>
        enum ScriptResults
        {
            Success = Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.DTSExecResult.Success,
            Failure = Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.DTSExecResult.Failure
        };
        #endregion

    }
}
```

Comment: Sometinh wierd I have tried to put your code but I got a error: ```    catch (Exception e)
            {
                Dts.Events.FireError(18, "sFTP Upload Error: {" + HostName + "}", e.ToString(), "", 0);
                Dts.TaskResult = (int)ScriptResults.Failure;
            }
        }
```
The name 'HostName' does not exist in the current context

Comment: I made an edit to declare the variables outside of the try block.  Could you try this new version?

Comment: Now I got this error: Use of unassigned local variable 'HostName'

Comment: Change the HostName declaration to this: `String HostName = "";` and see what error you get after that

Comment: I finally  got success, but Now I have this error: Error: 
WinSCP.SessionRemoteException: **Upload of file 'file_08072022.csv' was successful, but error occurred while setting the permissions and/or timestamp.**

If the problem persists, turn off setting permissions or preserving timestamp. Alternatively you can turn on 'Ignore permission errors' option.
If possible to changes the permissions using code in c#?

Comment: Try adding this setting in the transfer options: `transferOptions.PreserveTimestamp = false;`

Comment: *"I finally got success"* – So how did you "finally" get that error? The change suggested by @Mark could not have helped you getting there.  + Regarding the error you are getting now, see [Upload of file .. was successful, but error occurred while setting the permissions and/or timestamp. If the problem persists, turn off setting permissions or preserving timestamp. Alternatively you can turn on ‘Ignore permission errors’ option.](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/message_preserve_time_perm)